# manage.py works but foreman start errors out

Tags: python, django, heroku

This question is Heroku and django specific.

When I start my application using the command "python manage.py runserver", the webserver starts without error.  I can then go and retrieve the homepage my visiting localhost:8000 in my browser. Great.

When I start my application using the command "foreman start", the webserver also starts without error.  it reads

```
00:44:19 web.1  | started with pid 9736
00:44:19 web.1  | 2014-09-22 00:44:19 [9736] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.0.0
00:44:19 web.1  | 2014-09-22 00:44:19 [9736] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (9736)
00:44:19 web.1  | 2014-09-22 00:44:19 [9736] [INFO] Using worker: sync
00:44:19 web.1  | 2014-09-22 00:44:19 [9739] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9739
```

Awesome. When i try to visit localhost:5000, something goes awry. The page reads "Internal server error."  Huh.  I look at the stacktrace that foreman produces, and here is what I see:

```
00:45:22 web.1  |     respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
00:45:22 web.1  |   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 187, in __call__
00:45:22 web.1  |     self.load_middleware()
00:45:22 web.1  |   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 46, in load_middleware
00:45:22 web.1  |     for middleware_path in settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:
00:45:22 web.1  |   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
00:45:22 web.1  |     self._setup(name)
00:45:22 web.1  |   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 49, in _setup
00:45:22 web.1  |     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
00:45:22 web.1  |   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/sitepackages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 132, in __init__
00:45:22 web.1  |     % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e)
00:45:22 web.1  | ImportError: Could not import settings 'gettingstarted.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named 'dj_database_url'
```

dj_database_url did not import correctly. Weird. "Import dj_database_url" appears at the very top of my settings.py file.

If I activate my virtualenv and start python, I can run the command "import dj_database_url". Furthermore, when i start the server using manage.py, settings.py is opened, so the import must be working then as well.  So why would using foreman break this import?

Here is my wsgi.py:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "gettingstarted.settings")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Thank you in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `dj_database_url` is only installed in your virtual environment, make sure when you run `foreman` the environment is activated; otherwise you'll see the exception.

If you were to deploy this on Heroku, you would not have this problem because by default Heroku will install from your `requirements.txt` file and thus your environment will have `dj_database_url` and everything will work as expected.

I also see that you are using Python version 3.4 - unless you have a very specific need, try to use Python 2.7x as some libraries are still being ported to Python 3. You may run into unexplained errors later that are due to version incompatibility.

Comment: I thought maybe that was it, but I get the the same error regardless of whether virtualenv is activated :(

Comment: figured it out. You gave me the inspiration. It dawned on me that maybe not everything was properly installed in my virtual env. Turns out I was using a system level version of gunicorn. Thank you!